# Parallel Merge sort working on laptop but not on GPU and Xeon phi

Tags: c, openmp, gpu

```
void pmergesort(int a[], int l, int r)
{
   if (l < r)
      {
         int m = l+(r-l)/2;
         #pragma omp parallel
           {
              #pragma omp single
                {
                   #pragma omp task
                   pmergesort(a, l, m);
                }
          #pragma omp task
          pmergesort(a, m+1, r);
          #pragma omp taskwait 
          pmerge(a,l,m,r);
         }
     }
}
```

My professor told me to use #pragma omp single before only the first recursive call in order to make program much faster. It is working really fast on my laptop but it's not sorting properly on GPU and Xeon phi as these machines has more parallel threads.

Please let me know what can I do to make it faster and working proper on all machines.

Comment: Who know what you mean since the code is unformatted and the braces do not balance.

Comment: Apologies during pasting code it  happened, now I have changed it, Please have a look and let me know if you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel sort is very basic algorithm. Almost every parallel computing platform has sort API/sample code.

Here are some of them.

Thrust sort on GPU/CPU
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#sorting

CUB sort on GPU
https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/

Modern GPU sort on GPU
https://nvlabs.github.io/moderngpu/

TBB/openmp/cilk plus sort on CPU
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-parallel-stable-sort-using-c11-for-tbb-cilk-plus-and-openmp

OpenCL sort on Xeon Phi
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/bitonic-sorting.

Docs and code are all there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, actually I have checked on all of these links already, my professor wants  #pragma omp single before 1st recursive call and when I'm doing it, it's not working fine on GPU and Xeon processors, so he is saying to improve it but I have checked almost all links and found nothing to improve it.

Comment: @PragyaSharma Code running on GPU and Xeon Phi are quite different from OpenMP code. There's no chance that your code can run on GPU with one or two lines of modification. Basically you have to write a separate code for each computing platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric for your guidance, may you please help me little more what can I do to to make such function, which can run on both GPU and Xeon phi?? Should I share my program which I'm using right now???

Comment: @PragyaSharma You could start from Thrust sort. There's sample code in it's website.

Comment: Great thanks Eric, I checked about thrust sort I'll try to add this library and function in my program and looks like it will resolve my issue... :) :)